# Exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm trying to integrate spring and Hibernate with mysql. I created a simple java project and a package with 3 classes, an application context.xml file, and an hbm.xml for mapping. But after executing, I get this error:

**Error:**

```
Sep 17, 2014 1:27:49 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'd' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'template' while setting bean property 'template'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'template' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mysessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at com.javaspringhibernate.InsertTest.main(InsertTest.java:14)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'template' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mysessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:435)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1273)
    ... 36 more
```

This is the **Employee.java** file

```
package com.javaspringhibernate;

public class Employee {  
    private int id;  
    private String name;  
    private float salary;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public float getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(float salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public Employee() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }  

    //getters and setters  


    }
```

This is the     **InsertTest.java**

```
package com.javaspringhibernate;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;  
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;  
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;  
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;  

public class InsertTest {  
public static void main(String[] args) {  

    Resource r=new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");  
    BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(r);  

    EmployeeDao dao=(EmployeeDao)factory.getBean("d");  

    Employee e=new Employee();  
    e.setId(114);  
    e.setName("megha");  
    e.setSalary(50000);  

    dao.saveEmployee(e);  

}  
}
```

This is the **EmployeeDao.java**

```
package com.javaspringhibernate;

import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;  

public class EmployeeDao {  
HibernateTemplate template;  
public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template) {  
    this.template = template;  
}  

public void saveEmployee(Employee e){  
    template.save(e);  
}  

public void updateEmployee(Employee e){  
    template.update(e);  
}  

public void deleteEmployee(Employee e){  
    template.delete(e);  
}  
}
```

This is the **employee.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">


<hibernate-mapping>  
<class name="com.javaspringhibernate.Employee" table="emp558">  
          <id name="id">  
          <generator class="assigned"></generator>  
          </id>  

          <property name="name"></property>  
          <property name="salary"></property>  
</class>  

</hibernate-mapping>
```

This is the **applicationContext.xml**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" >
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdb" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />

</bean> 

    <bean id="mysessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  

        <property name="mappingResources">  
        <list>  
        <value>employee.hbm.xml</value>  
        </list>  
        </property>  

        <property name="hibernateProperties">  
            <props>  
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  

            </props>  
        </property>  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">  
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="d" class="com.javaspringhibernate.EmployeeDao">  
    <property name="template" ref="template"></property>  
    </bean>  

</beans>
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue? if yes, how did you do it?

Answer (score 30):

Your problem is `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` on `"dataSource"` bean.

If using maven add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

else add this library [commons-dbcp-jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.2.2/commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar) in your classpath.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Spring 4+, you should use `SessionFactory`. Also, you need these jars: **commons-pool**, **commons-dbcp**.

This is a sample code that I made, I hope it helps you:

```
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO{

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void saveEmployee(Employee e) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(e);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

`applicationContext.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"> 
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin@:..." />
        <property name="username" value="admin" />
        <property name="password" value="admin" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>

        <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>employee.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="d" class="com.orm.EmployeeDAOImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like that jvm could not find the **org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource** class.Please check in your class-path or in your project build-path that **commons-dbcp.jar** is present or not.

If yes then,  open your **commons-dbcp.jar** and check that particular class(**org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource**) is available or not

Answer (score 6):

change `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` to `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource`,it works well

Answer (score 2):

`springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource` instead of `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` in `applicationContext.xml` file. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same Exception stack with DBCP2.  The issue was that my local m2 cache of the JAR file was corrupt.  After I deleted it,  Maven said it could not download 2.1.1.  I switched to 2.5.0 and the app loaded successfully.